# How can I use file stream duplication to pipe stdout and stderr?

Tags: bash, shell

Give a command to run *"foo"* such that its output is piped into the program *"pout"* and its errors are piped into the program *"perr"*,
and that all output from *"pout"* is on stdout, and all output from *"perr"* is on standard error.  Use file stream duplication. Do not use named pipes.

I couldn't figure out how stream duplication works, so I tried doing it using normal pipes. Some help understanding stream duplication would be great.

```
( ./foo | ./pout ) 2>&1 | ./perr
```

Comment: Problem statement is ambiguous. In phrase "its errors are piped", which program is "it"?

Comment: Oh, ok. Sorry about that. That's the way the question was handed to me. I guess "its errors ..." refers to "foo".

Comment: "Stream duplication" is an odd piece of terminology. *Technically* I suppose it's correct, since redirections are performed using the `dup2()` syscall, but that happens at the file descriptor layer, not the stream layer (which is a C-standard-library abstraction). It would be much more typical to use the word "redirection".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial.  Let's see how this applies to your example:

Let's make some shell functions for trying things out:

```
# Some helper to show you what is is going on with the file descriptors:
function lofd { lsof -ad 0,1,2,3,4 -p $BASHPID -w; }
# foo's stdout goes into pout, foo's stderr goes to perr:
function foo { echo foo-out; echo foo-err 1>&2; lofd; }
function pout { sed 's/foo-out/pout-out/'; echo pout-err 1>&2; lofd; }
function perr { sed 's/foo-err/perr-out/'; echo perr-err 1>&2; lofd; }
```

Check `foo`'s output to `stderr` and `stdout`:

```
foo 1>out 2>err
grep "" out err
```

Pipe `foo` through `pout`, with `pout` also printing to `stderr` and `stdout`:

```
{ foo | pout; } 1>out 2>err
grep "" out err
```

Ensure all output from `pout` goes to `stdout`:

```
{ foo | pout 2>&1; } 1>out 2>err
grep "" out err
```

Now it gets tricky: when we pipe this through `perr` (ensuring that all output from `perr` goes to `stderr`), we see that `perr` gets the input from `pout`, and the `stderr` from `foo` just passes:

```
{ { foo | pout 2>&1; } | perr 1>&2; } 1>out 2>err # not as intended
grep "" out err
```

We can only manage this with the help of some temporary file descriptors. For one thing, we use fd 3 as a backup for the `stdout`.  This can then be used by `pout` to "bypass" the pipe into `perr`:

```
{ { { foo | pout 1>&3 2>&3; } | perr 1>&2; } 3>&1; } 1>out 2>err
grep "" out err
```

Moreover, we use fd 4 to handover the pipe into `perr` such that `foo` can use it:

```
{ { { foo 2>&4 | pout 1>&3 2>&3; } 4>&1 | perr 1>&2; } 3>&1; } 1>out 2>err
grep "" out err
```

Finally, some cleanups (closing unused file descriptors: take a look at the `lsof` output to see what is going on here):

```
{ { { foo 2>&4 3>&- 4>&- | pout 1>&3 2>&3 3>&- 4>&-; } 4>&1 | perr 1>&2 3>&-; } 3>&1; } 1>out 2>err
grep "" out err
```

Without our debugging context:

```
{ { foo 2>&4 3>&- 4>&- | pout 1>&3 2>&3 3>&- 4>&-; } 4>&1 | perr 1>&2 3>&-; } 3>&1
```

Et voila.

Answer (score 1):

use another pipe (here 5)

```
( ( ./foo | ./pout ) 2>&1 1>&5 | ./perr ) 5>&1
```

- `2>&1` redirect stderr to stdout
- `1>&5` redirect stdout to pipe5
- `./perr` doesn't see stdout of `./pout`
- `5>&1` redirect pipe5 to stdout again.